# Button-styled list-box doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have 2 listboxes in my app that use

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="WrapPanelTemplate">
        <WrapPanel Width="290"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonItemTemplate">
        <Button Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="120" Margin="3,2,3,2" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Everything looks great but when I try to click on them they do not select a new item. I have SelectedItem bound to a property on my view-model but whenever I select a new item the set method does not happen. I have a regular listbox that is hooked up in the same way and does work. Here is the implementation of the custom listbox:

```
<ListBox Height="284" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="faveProgramsButtons" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FavoriteAppList}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FavoriteAppList_SelectedApp}" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="281" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapPanelTemplate}"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonItemTemplate}">
</ListBox>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `Button` is swallowing the mouse click so the `ListBoxItem` in the `ListBox` never receives it, hence it is never selected. If you want to be able to select the items when you click the `Button` you can try using a `ToggleButton` instead and bind `IsChecked` to `IsSelected`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonItemTemplate">
    <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="120" Margin="3,2,3,2" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                      Path=IsSelected,
                                      Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

You could also achieve this with a little code behind or an attached behavior.

**ButtonItemTemplate**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonItemTemplate">
    <Button Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="120" Margin="3,2,3,2"
            Click="TemplateButton_Click"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void TemplateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = GetVisualParent<ListBoxItem>(clickedButton);
    if (listBoxItem != null)
    {
        listBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
    }
}

public static T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject child = childObject as DependencyObject;
    // iteratively traverse the visual tree
    while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }
    return child as T;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have to check it out when I get to work tomorrow.